# How to skip the payment method step in checkout process in Magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2, magento2.3, magento-2.0

I have magento Open Source 2.3.2 setup my client don't want any payment method now. How to remove payment method step in checkout process. I just want to place order without selection payment method.

Any suggestion welcome in advanced.

Below is the exact representation of the requirement.

[image]

Comment: by default enable COD for payment, so customer placed order without selecting payment method,  but its just show in backend order view

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. As you know COD also one type of payment method. In my requirement is, after customer choosing the shipping method directly need to place the order without selecting any payment methods. if you know please help. thanks in advanced.

Comment: magento doesn't placed order without payment, if you want that type of requirement then do customise for selecting payment by default